# div stretches to 100% of its parent's height, instead of just filling the rest of the space, but only when a child is overflowing

Tags: css, flexbox

Some context first:

I'm trying to create a scrollable content area.
In reality this is a React app that will asynchronously populate the scrollable area with records from a database.
But the following is enough to illustrate the issue I'm facing, which is purely styling related.

I have the following html structure:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
  <div class="app">
                <header class="main-head">The header</header>
                <nav class="main-nav">
                </nav>
                <article class="content">
          <div class="component">
              <div>just here as a placeholder to whatever pushes the div below down</div>
              <div class="table-view">
                <div class="table-content-wrapper">
                  <div class="table-content" style="height:1410px;">
                    scrollable rows go here
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
                </article>
                <footer class="main-footer">The footer</footer>
            </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And accompanying CSS

```
index
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.main-head {
    min-width: 0;
    min-height: 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
    grid-area: header;
}

.content {
    min-width: 0;
    min-height: 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
    grid-area: content;
}

.main-nav {
    min-width: 0;
    min-height: 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
    grid-area: nav;
}

.main-footer {
    min-width: 0;
    min-height: 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
    grid-area: footer;
}

.app {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 20px;
    grid-template-areas: "header" "nav" "content" "footer";
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 10fr 1fr;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

@media (min-width: 700px) {
    .app {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 5fr;
        grid-template-rows: 2fr 25fr 1fr;
        grid-template-areas: "header header" "nav content" "footer footer"
    }

    nav ul {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
}

.component {
  height:100%;
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:column;
}

.table-view {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #fff;

  display:flex;
  flex-flow:column;
}

.table-content-wrapper {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}

.table-content {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

The issue lies with the table's content.

First of all: take note of the explicit style height on the `table-content div`. This is set dynamically by the React app in order to create an accurate scroll bar on the `table-content-wrapper div` and is based on the total number of records the dataset contains multiplied by the set row height.

The problem is when `table-content-wrapper` is in overflow mode, i.e. when there are more records than can be shown in the height that is available. This makes the `table-view div` stretch to the total **height of** the `component div`, **as opposed to** only taking up the **height** that is still **available in** the `component div` (i.e.: `component div` height minus `placeholder div` height).

This is easily demonstrated by running [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e4h3pj5t/) and seeing what happens when you remove the explicit height style from the `table-content div`. You'll see that the height of the `table-view div` is then reduced by the height taken up by the `placeholder div`, and as such now accurately stays within the bounds of the `content article` element. But then obviously there is no more scrolling.

So I guess the question boils down to: how do I make it so that the `table-view div` does not grow beyond the space that is available in the `component div`, while allowing the `table-content-wrapper div` to be in overflow mode using the explicit height style?

**UPDATE 1**

Going by the first comments, it seems this might be a *cannot reproduce in browser X* kind of situation; so here is some additional clarification:

- I am seeing this behavior in both Brave and Chrome, in both normal and privacy mode (extensions are ruled out, I don't have any).
- This is a screenshot **with** the height style. You can clearly see the border of the div going out of the `content article` element [image: with height style]
- This is a screenshot **without** the height style. You can clearly see the border of the div respecting the `content article` element bounds [image: without height style]

Comment: This question lacks clarity. Maybe you can break it down, or otherwise simplify it,  a bit more.

Comment: How exactly?
This is as clear as it gets, I've already dumbed it down as much as I can while maintaining this behavior. Just run the fiddle and see what happens.

To summarize again: The `table-view div` should not grow bigger than the remaining space in its parent (therefor remaining inside the bounds of the `content article` element), while allowing its child (`table-content-wrapper div`) to overflow when its child's (`table-content div`) height is set to something higher than the visible space available.

Comment: That's what I mean. Everything you're describing in your question, and in your comment above, appears to be working already. What browser are you using?

Comment: I'm checking in Chrome, and here's what I'm seeing:

Comment: *"The `table-view div` should not grow bigger than the remaining space in its parent..."* Working.

Comment: *"...(therefore remaining inside the bounds of the `content article` element)..."*  Working.

Comment: *"...while allowing its child (`table-content-wrapper div`) to overflow when its child's (`table-content div`) height is set to something higher than the visible space available.*" Working.

Comment: I added an update to the OP.
You're not seeing what the screenshots there show?

Comment: Try adding `min-height: 0` to `.table-view`. https://jsfiddle.net/oc7sjy4z/1/

Comment: Sigh, I always figured it was going to be a one-liner solution, but this just hurts :D
Can you explain *why* this works?

Comment: You already have the `min-width: 0` and `min-height: 0` overrides throughout your code. They replace the `min-width: auto` and `min-height: auto` default settings for flex / grid items. With this default setting, a flex / grid item cannot be smaller than it's content (`auto`) by default.

Comment: You were just missing this setting in that particular level of items in the hierarchy. It was like a missing link in the chain.

Comment: Your post is actually discussed in detail in another post. So I'll close your question as a duplicate, if that's okay with you.

Comment: Also, on a unrelated note, there are syntax errors in your HTML. In the `main-nav` and `table-content` elements, the class attributes are missing the equals sign.

Comment: Yeah go ahead with the duplicate. I figured this wouldn't be the first, but I didn't really know what to look for as I'm not *that* proficient in the latest CSS stuff, so I posted anyway.
Thanks a ton! It makes sense now :)
(I'll update the HTML, I clearly threw it together too quickly)